# how to assign value to asp:label in jquery mobile application

Tags: jquery, .net, jquery-mobile

I have this code in  tag.
 i am calling this **function setmessage** from code behind.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setmessage(msg) {
$.mobile.changePage( "#pagethree", { transition: "slideup", changeHash: true });
        document.getElementById('<%= lbl_msg.ClientID %>').Text = msg;
}
    </script>
```

Can you please tell me why **'lbl_msg'** it is not getting updated.

Comment: Make sure you don't have duplicate IDs inside same `document`. If each page has the same ID, the first element with that ID will be changed.

Comment: Yes i don't have same id...i checked it

Comment: what does `<%= lbl_msg.ClientID %>` print? can you show us?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
document.getElementById('<%= lbl_msg.ClientID %>').innerHTML = msg;
```

or:

```
document.getElementById('<%= lbl_msg.ClientID %>').textContent = msg;
```

instead of:

```
document.getElementById('<%= lbl_msg.ClientID %>').Text = msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById will only run on the first instance it finds of that particular tag id anywhere in the DOM. Therefore you need to identify the current page and then look for the required id on that page.

You can do this by using the following code:

```
var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");

$("YOUR TARGET ID HERE", activePage)[0].innerHTML = "YOUR TEXT HERE";
```

Its also worth noting that innerHTML renders upto 3 times quicker than other methods such as append. It will therefore also likely be much faster than using Server Side Tech such as .Net.

Ive also noticed that sometimes playing around with the page events in which you fire actions in JQM can make a huge difference. This is usually due to your action firing before an element is available to the JQuery. For the sake of debugging, try adding the message to the label via the pagecontainershow event or one of the other. If the message shows you know its an event order issue, and youll have to reconsider your script.